# Does the new Google Search Console contain the SEO audit report in its previous version?

Tags: google-search-console

I used to play with Google Search Console for many years ago and I remembered the old console has a SEO audit report. It can tell me what pages have duplicated titles or missing h1 tags.

It's a very helpful report to fix/improve my whole site's bad pages.

However, I can't find it in the new Google Search Console. And I also failed to find an entrance to the previous version.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Search Console used to have a section called "HTML Improvements". Here is a screenshot ([image source](https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/reviving-search-console/)):

[image: Google Search Console HTML Improvements]

Google removed the report and is not planning to replace it.  [Google says](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9073702?hl=en):

> No equivalent report provided; please follow [best practices to improve your titles and snippets](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624).

I wouldn't have tried to rely on the report as a full SEO audit.  It only reported on problems with titles and meta descriptions.  It didn't address a whole range of possible SEO problems including redirects, canonicals, thin content, plagarism, usability, robots.txt, link structure, security, mobile friendliness, headings, alt text, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Google removed this report from the new version of the tool, now called Google Search Console.

As a free alternative (although a bit limited) you can try downloading and using [Screaming Frog SEO Spider](https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/seo-spider/) that can analyze your website and shows this plus much more.